# xsl 1.0 document () reference based on variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I could not find any existing posts that answered this specific problem.  Hopefully it is an easy answer for someone more familiar with XSL:  I have a XSL stylesheet that is applied to a XML file generated by a part inspection software system, which then reads the resulting HTML code....

I would like to add an external XML file that contains tolerances for each different part number.  So i was imagining the XSL sheet would need to use a document() reference with either the document name or an element in the document defined by the name of an element from the source XML file.  Hopefully the included code illustrates what i am trying to do.  Obviously it does not work as it stands and is also only a snippet of the whole file....

Thanks for any help or links to something I can learn from.

```
<xsl:variable name="pname">
    <xsl:value-of select="//NAME/."/>.xml
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="TUBE_LRA_ERRORS">
<table border="0" style="font-size:18pt">
    <tr><th><xsl:copy-of select="//NAME/."/></th></tr>
    <tr><th><xsl:value-of select="//REPORT/REPORT_TIME"/></th></tr>
    <tr><th>LRA Errors</th></tr>
</table>
<table border="1" style="font-size:26pt">
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#cccccc">
    <td>#</td><td>L</td><td>R</td><td>A</td>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="ERROR">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="X > document('$pname')/l/hi">
                <td bgcolor="00FFFF" style="font-weight:600">
            <xsl:value-of select="X"/></td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="X > document('tolerances.xml')/l/lo">
                <td bgcolor="ffffff" style="font-weight:200">
                    <xsl:value-of select="X"/></td>
            </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you have in mind is that the variable `pname` will have the name of the tolerances file and you want to check values from that? It should be possible to do so.

This will not work:

```
<xsl:when test="X > document('$pname')/l/hi">
   <td bgcolor="00FFFF" style="font-weight:600">
        <xsl:value-of select="X"/>
   </td>
</xsl:when>
```

because you have "$pname" in quotes and this would cause it to look for a file *called* "$pname". However, this would load the file whose name is the value of `$pname` (note I've removed the single quotes around `$pname`:

```
<xsl:when test="X > document($pname)/l/hi">
   <td bgcolor="00FFFF" style="font-weight:600">
        <xsl:value-of select="X"/>
   </td>
</xsl:when>
```

Or if you wanted to use a file whose name was the value of `$pname` plus ".xml", you could do this:

```
<xsl:when test="X > document(concat($pname, '.xml'))/l/hi">
   <td bgcolor="00FFFF" style="font-weight:600">
        <xsl:value-of select="X"/>
   </td>
</xsl:when>
```

I think you may have a logic error here:

```
<xsl:when test="X > document('tolerances.xml')/l/lo">
  <td bgcolor="ffffff" style="font-weight:200">
    <xsl:value-of select="X"/>
  </td>
</xsl:when>
```

I'm guessing you want to show the special formatting when `X` is *less than* the `lo` value, in which case you would need:

```
<xsl:when test="X &lt; document('tolerances.xml')/l/lo">
```

Comment: why, thanks!  I figured it might be simple!  As for the logic error, it only looks that way because the rest of the conditional formatting went on for another page or three so I left it out.  Thanks again.